# Efficiently selecting from rows with max and min timestamps

Tags: t-sql

For each project we have a number of tasks. I need to find the tasktype on the first and last task on each project. I tried the following to get the first tasktype and planned on doing something similar for the last:

```
SELECT projects.ProjectNumber,
    COALESCE(
        (SELECT Tasktype 
         FROM [Facts].[ProjectTable] pt 
         WHERE 
             pt.ProjectNumber=projects.ProjectNumber 
             AND pt.Timestamp = 
                 (SELECT MIN(x.Timestamp) 
                 FROM [Facts].[ProjectTable] x 
                 where 
                     x.ProjectNumber = projects.ProjectNumber
                 )
         ),-1) AS [First Tasktype]
FROM [Facts].[ProjectTable] projects
GROUP BY projects.ProjectNumber
```

But performance is very slow (I'm sure 2 nested subqueries aren't helping). How do I get the first and last tasktype for each project efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
from 
( 
select ProductNumber, TaskType
     , row_number() over (partition by ProductNumber order by Timestamp asc)  ttasc  
     , row_number() over (partition by ProductNumber order by Timestamp desc) ttdesc 
  FROM [Facts].[ProjectTable]
) tt   
where tt.ttasc = 1 or tt.ttdesc = 1
```

or on one row

```
with cte as
( 
select ProductNumber, TaskType
     , row_number() over (partition by ProductNumber order by Timestamp asc)  ttasc  
     , row_number() over (partition by ProductNumber order by Timestamp desc) ttdesc 
  FROM [Facts].[ProjectTable]
)
select * 
from cte as cte1 
join cte as cte2 
      on cte1.ProductNumber = cte2.ProductNumber 
     and cte1.ttasc  = 1 
     and cte2.ttdesc = 1
```

Comment: Interesting. Will look into it at work tomorrow, but will try to modify it so I get both first and last tasktype on the same row.

Comment: Just make it a cte and then a self join on the cte

Comment: Thanks! This performs a lot better than what I initially did. Might want to delete the first solution.

Comment: There are people that may benefit from the first

Comment: Ok. Other edits would be the "tt.ttadesc" in the first proposed solution should be "tt.ttdesc" if you want to keep it and also the subquery needs a "From" statement in both solutions. Thanks again though :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but try this query.
I think, this query give you the same results

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  projects.ProjectNumber,
  COALESCE(pt.Tasktype, -1) AS [First Tasktype]
FROM Facts.ProjectTable projects
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Tasktype, ProjectNumber, MIN(Timestamp)
           FROM Facts.ProjectTable
           GROUP BY Tasktype, ProjectNumber) pt
ON pt.ProjectNumber = projects.ProjectNumber
--GROUP BY projects.ProjectNumber
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I get multiple lines with same projectnumber and tasktype (because of no grouping?).

Comment: add distinct... i modify